# Install Ubuntu on tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-for-android

1) How can I download Ubuntu for tablet?
2) How can I install and replace it with my android OS and install it on my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can find info [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/linux/how-install-ubuntu-touch-image-3531970/). It is recommended that you not perform this on your main device.

Comment: Thanks and one more question how can I customize it for example disable some parts of it?